# clearTimeout and clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I am creating a countdown with `setInterval` and `setTimeout` its working fine but when I stop this on button click it stops after completing the current Countdown.

**Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPgjKo)**

> What I want is to simply create a countdown with interval . When user
>   click on start poll it will send an ajax request with every 10 sec and
>   display the countdown to the next request

I used the following code to stop Timer. This is a repeatable timeout.

```
$(document).on('click', '#stop_poll', function(){
        $('.my_clock span').html('0');
        for (var i = 1; i < activeCountdowns.length; i++)
            clearCountdown(i);

        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(interval);
    })
```

```js
var interval;
(function(){
    window.activeCountdowns = [];
    window.setCountdown = function (code, delay, callback, interval) {
        var timeout = delay;
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            clearCountdown(timeoutId);
            return code();
        }, delay);
        window.activeCountdowns.push(timeoutId);
        setTimeout(function countdown(){
            var key = window.activeCountdowns.indexOf(timeoutId);
            if (key < 0) return;
            timeout -= interval;
            setTimeout(countdown, interval);
            return callback(timeout);
        }, interval);
        return timeoutId;
    };
    window.clearCountdown = function (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        var key = window.activeCountdowns.indexOf(timeoutId);
        if (key < 0) return;
        window.activeCountdowns.splice(key, 1);
    };
})();
var mySetInterval = function(time)
{
    myClearInterval();
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        var t = setCountdown(function () {
            $('.my_clock span').html('0');
        },  time * 1000, function (i) {
            $('.my_clock span').html(i / 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }, time * 1000);
}
var myClearInterval = function()
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#stop_poll', function(){
        $('.my_clock span').html('0');
        for (var i = 1; i < activeCountdowns.length; i++)
            clearCountdown(i);
        
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(interval);
    })
  
  $(document).on('click', '#start_poll', function(){
      var pollinterval = 10
        setCountdown(function () {
            //some code
            },  pollinterval * 1000, function (i) {
                $('.my_clock span').html(i / 1000);
            }, 1000);
        mySetInterval(pollinterval);
    })
});
```

```css
a#stop_poll {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
button#start_poll {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="start_poll" name="start_poll" class="btn btn-primary">Start Polling</button>
<a id="stop_poll" name="stop_poll" id="stop_poll" class="btn btn-default">Stop Polling</a>
<div class="my_clock alert alert-info">
     <p>next poll in <span>0</span>s</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?

Comment: I didn't get any answer

Comment: Why do you use such a complicated code for a simple countdown? Try to simplify your code and test it again.

Comment: @SapuSeven I am not so good at javascript. I am a PHP developer. I create this code with the help of google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is an easier solution of what you want to do.
Start your `ajax` request in the `pollServer()` function, right where i put the comment.

```js
var serverPollIntervall = 10;
var serverPollInt;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.my_clock').html("<p>waiting for poll</p>");
   $('#start_poll').on('click',function(){
      pollServer();
   });

   $('#stop_poll').on('click',function(){
      clearInterval(serverPollInt);
      $('.my_clock').html("<p>waiting for poll</p>");
   });
})

function pollServer() {
  //do the countdown text
  var count = serverPollIntervall;
  
  serverPollInt = setInterval(function(){
  count = count -1;
     $('.my_clock').html("<p>next poll in "+count+" s</p>");
    
     if(count == 0)
     {
       count = 10;
       //send the ajax request
     }
    
   },1000);
}
```

```css
a#stop_poll {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
button#start_poll {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="start_poll" name="start_poll" class="btn btn-primary">Start Polling</button>
<a id="stop_poll" name="stop_poll" id="stop_poll" class="btn btn-default">Stop Polling</a>
<div class="my_clock alert alert-info">

 </div>
```

Comment: just to get your question right, you want to stop that countdown on button click immediately. When restart again, you would like to continue at the last countdown value or start a new countdown from 10? ... please clearify in your question :)

Comment: What I want is to simply create a countdown with interval . When user click on start poll it will send an ajax request with every 10 sec and display the countdown to the next request

Comment: i.e on click countdown will say `next poll in 10,9,8,7.....0 s` and on 0 it will again send the ajax request until the user clicks on stop poll button.

Comment: @ManojKumar I edited my answer to an easier solution, please have a look if that's what you wanted.

Comment: you are great, Thanks. This is really a clean and simple solution